# Creating Charts in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, charts

Since I don't like the idea of paying $100 for a chart-engine, I stepped on this article:

[Codeguru.com - How to create charts](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/article.php/c20199/How-to-Create-Charts--Graphs-in-Your-Windows-Phone-Application.htm)

The result of it looks very rough though, is there a way to style and change the axes of such a self-made chart?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own style and apply it to the chart control. Here is another option you can look into as well: http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick

Comment: Are you kidding me? Pay 99 Euros yourself.

Comment: That article does not describe a self-made chart. It shows you how to use the Silverlight Toolkit chart: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888

Comment: You don't have to pay 99 Euros. It says it is free and open source.  Here is a link to the source code: https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts

Comment: @Clue: I would recommend a less aggressive tone. You may not wish to pay, but people here are taking their time to try to help you.

Comment: No they are obviously not. Don't you know, that those companies roll out their people to market a specific product? If you didn't notice Dan, such comments ("use this engine") always have the intention to sell something. Just search here in Stackoverflow for `Charts in Silverlight` and you will see what's on.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped upon a great chart making library when I was making my application, Its called [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/blog/2010/07/19/windows-phone-7-charts/). I hope it helps you too.  Sample projects are available on [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Charts-Gauges-in-WP7-a25c6958) too